# Is there anything like entryId to uniquely identify the MailItem in outlook vsto?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to use an id of mail item to use as a name of userproperty to store a value..
The problem i am facing is that entry id is too much long that i can't use it as a user property name.
I want an alternative of it the main focus is unique identifier for mailitem

Answer (score 0):

You should never use an entry id or any identifier like that as a name of a user property - named properties are a scarce resource, you can have at most 0xFFFF of them in a particular mailbox. Once you reach that limit, your mailbox is dead.

Why would you ever use an entry id as a *name* (rather than a value) of a property?

Comment: I need to store some value in a mail user property and will fetch that value with a unique identifier for my business. I am using user property as a local storage to get and set value ..

Comment: That's fine, but its name must be constant, and only the value can change.

Comment: yes it will remain constant I have done it with another logic.
Can you please tell me when we add user property with its name and value on a mailitem so when we delete that mailttem user property is also deleted or not ? or is there any folder of user property in outlook ?

Comment: and one more question please 
Is there any limit of storing user property in a user account ? will it slow down the outlook ?  Thanks in advance Mr. Dmitry Streblechenko

Comment: Since the property is stored on the item itself, it will be gone when the item is deleted. User property is like any other property (such as Subject) there is no limit on how maay times you can set it, there is only a limit on the number of unique property names that you can use.

Comment: And if you need to store information about deleted items, you might want avoid storing the property on the item itself - the standard solution is to store the data on the hidden (associated) item in the parent folder or one of the standard folders (such as Inbox or Calendar). See MAPIFolder.GetStorage - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.getstorage?view=outlook-pia